# Which HTML tags may NOT contain an event handler?

Tags: html, event-handling

I am currently working on a test for a web design class and there is only one question I can't figure out.

Which of the following tags may NOT contain an event handler?

A. `<img>`
B. `<form>`
C. `<head>`
D. `<select>`

I have searched several times using different phrasing, and from what Google shows me, all of these are able to contain event handlers. I am not really sure what else to do other than ask here! Any links that could guide me would be helpful also!

Comment: Simple answer, all of them. Inline event handlers are the wrong approach 99% of the time.

Comment: None of them. You can attach event handlers to any element. The person asking is probably looking for `<head>`, but they are wrong. http://jsbin.com/oGABiWi/1/

Comment: depends on the type of event. For example `onsubmit` may contain only `<form>` (and maybe `input`)

Comment: I don't really understand why this is getting downvoted. It's a legitimate question, and it sounds like OP is suffering from a bad instructor.

Comment: This is the only question I was unable or unsure of, I assume <head> however from researching, all of these tags may contain event handlers, which is why I came here to see if anyone maybe knew what answer they may have been looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those elements may contain inline event handlers.

[HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#global-attributes)

> The following event handler content attributes may be specified on any HTML element:
>
> - onabort
> - onblur*
> - oncancel
> - oncanplay
> - oncanplaythrough
> - onchange
> - onclick
> - onclose
> - oncontextmenu
> - oncuechange
> - ondblclick
> - ondrag
> - ondragend
> - ondragenter
> - ondragexit
> - ondragleave
> - ondragover
> - ondragstart
> - ondrop
> - ondurationchange
> - onemptied
> - onended
> - onerror*
> - onfocus*
> - oninput
> - oninvalid
> - onkeydown
> - onkeypress
> - onkeyup
> - onload*
> - onloadeddata
> - onloadedmetadata
> - onloadstart
> - onmousedown
> - onmouseenter
> - onmouseleave
> - onmousemove
> - onmouseout
> - onmouseover
> - onmouseup
> - onmousewheel
> - onpause
> - onplay
> - onplaying
> - onprogress
> - onratechange
> - onreset
> - onscroll*
> - onseeked
> - onseeking
> - onselect
> - onshow
> - onsort
> - onstalled
> - onsubmit
> - onsuspend
> - ontimeupdate
> - onvolumechange
> - onwaiting